# Streaming from an isp camera with rtsp protocol. I recieved an errors from client VLC applicaton

Tags: python, gstreamer

Need help to for streaming an isp camera over Ethernet with rtps protocol. I have the code listed below.
Problem: I can not watch stream from client using vlc application

```
source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("qtiqmmfsrc", "qmmf-source")
framefilter = Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter",   "frame-filter")
decoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvv4l2decoder", "nvv4l2-decoder")
converter = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvvidconv", "video-converter")
encoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvv4l2h264enc", "h264-encoder")
muxer = Gst.ElementFactory.make("mpegtsmux", "mpegts-muxer")
parse = Gst.ElementFactory.make("h264parse",    "h264-parse")
queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make("queue",        "queue")
sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("udpsink", "udp-sink")

# set properties to the elements
source.set_property("camera", camera_id)

if camera_id == 0:
    framefilter.set_property("caps", Gst.Caps.from_string(
        "video/x-h264,format=NV12 framerate=30/1,width=1920, height=1080"))
else:
    framefilter.set_property("caps", Gst.Caps.from_string(
        "video/x-h264, framerate=30/1,width=1280, height=720"))

sink.set_property("host", sys.argv[2])
sink.set_property("port", port)

rtppay = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtph264pay", "rtppay")

# Build the pipeline
pipeline.add(source)
pipeline.add(parse)
pipeline.add(framefilter)
pipeline.add(muxer)
pipeline.add(queue)
pipeline.add(sink)

if not Gst.Element.link(source, parse):
    print("ERROR: Could not link source to h264parser")
    sys.exit(1)
if not Gst.Element.link(parse, framefilter):
    print("ERROR: Could not link h264parser to decoder")
    sys.exit(1)
if not Gst.Element.link(framefilter, muxer):
    print("ERROR: Could not link capsfilter to converter")
    sys.exit(1)
if not Gst.Element.link(muxer, queue):
    print("ERROR: Could not link muxer to queue")
    sys.exit(1)
if not Gst.Element.link(queue, sink):
    print("ERROR: Could not link queue to sink")
    sys.exit(1)
try:
    print("Streaming started...")
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

    print("vlc at ip:%s:%d" % (sys.argv[2], port))
    print('Press Ctrl+C to stop')
    loop.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Streaming stopped due to keyboard Interrupt")
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Need to help if my setup pipeline is correct!
My goal is to have camera stream over ethernet with low latency

Answer (score 0):

This a MPEG TS streaming pipeline, not an RTSP pipeline. If you really want RTSP you need to use GStreamer's RTSP server. Here are some examples:

https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/tree/main/subprojects/gst-rtsp-server/examples